# the output vlaue isn't the sme as the value i have entered to a file when i enter 21 thw output of x =50?

Tags: java

```
package file;
import java.io.*;

public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileWriter fs = new FileWriter("ahmed.txt");
            fs.write("21");

            fs.close();
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("ahmed.txt");
            //String x = Integer.toString(fr.read());
            int x = fr.read();
            System.out.println(x);
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {                 
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

the output value of x is 50 when the input is 20 and 21 what should i do to
         make the input  the output

Comment: Sounds like it's reading the byte, since the ASCII value of 2 is `50`.

Comment: Well, it's reading a single character. That could consist of more than one byte. But it's certainly not going to read *multiple* characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why does it output 50

You are reading the first byte from the file, the character `2` has the ASCII value 50, so the first byte of the stream has the value 50

## How should I read an int from a file

You can use a scanner and the method nextInt() to read the number from the file

## Working code

```
public class x {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      FileWriter fs = new FileWriter("ahmed.txt");
      fs.write("21");

      fs.close();
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("ahmed.txt");
      //String x = Integer.toString(fr.read());
      Scanner s = new Scanner(fr);
      int x = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println(x);
      s.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

## General improvements

Using try-with-resources may make the code cleaner, and also fix the leaks the current code has

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with you, using the wrong API

> int x = fr.read();

See below.

```
       fs.close();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("ahmed.txt");
        //String x = Integer.toString(fr.read());
        //int x = fr.read();
        //System.out.println(x);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
        fr.close();
```

If you still want to use your kind of code, use this:

```
            int x = fr.read();
            String xs = String.valueOf( (char) x );
            System.out.println(xs);

            x = fr.read();
             xs = String.valueOf( (char) x );
            System.out.println(xs);
```

Important to note is `String xs = String.valueOf( (char) x );` which does conversion of ascii value to String